# Getting object from stream JAVA

Tags: java, object, methods, return, java-stream

I am trying to find  Friend by firstName and lastName  using stream. Is it possible to return object from this stream? Like friend with that name and lastname? Because now return is mismatched.

```
@Override
public Friend findFriend(String firstName, String lastName) throws FriendNotFoundException { 
    if (firstName == null || lastName ==null) {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("There is no parameters");
    }

           List<Friend> result = friends.stream()
            .filter(x -> (firstName.equals(x.getFirstName())) && 
            (lastName.equals(x.getLastName()))))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

            return result;
```

Comment: Call `findAny()` or `findFirst()` instead of `collect()`.

Answer (score 2):

utilize [**`findFirst`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--) like so:

```
return friends.stream()
              .filter(x -> firstName.equals(x.getFirstName()) && 
                            lastName.equals(x.getLastName())
                     )
              .findFirst().orElse(null);
```

or return an [**`Optional<Friend>`**](http://www.baeldung.com/java-optional) i.e:

```
@Override
public Optional<Friend> findFriend(String firstName, String lastName) throws FriendNotFoundException { 
       if (firstName == null || lastName == null) {
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("There is no parameters");
       }

       return friends.stream()
              .filter(x -> firstName.equals(x.getFirstName()) && 
                            lastName.equals(x.getLastName())
                     )
              .findFirst();
}
```

which then means the method you're overriding must also be declared to return an `Optional<Friend>` and so forth up the inheritance hierarchy if needed.

Comment: Nice hint with the Optional. You might want to use `findAny()`, though. It might be more efficient for large streams.

Comment: @MalteHartwig true, I would recommend `findAny` when performing bulk operations with parallelStream as it's less constraining to use `findAny` in such case rather than to use `findFirst`.